# Can you compress bytes in python and send them?

Tags: python, tcp

I am writing a TCP python script, and I need the first 4 bytes to be the size of the file.

I got the size of the file by doing

```
SIZE_OF_FILE = os.path.getsize(infile.name)
```

The size is 392399 bytes.

When I do

```
s.send(str(SIZE_OF_FILE).encode("utf-8"))
```

it sends the file, and then on my server I have

```
fileSize = conn.recv(4).decode('utf-8')
```

This should read the first 4 bytes, and extract the file size information, but it returns 3923 instead of the 392399.

as the file size... what happened? "392399" should be able to fit into 4 bytes.

We are suppose to be using big endian.

Comment: yeah, but not _as string_... check `struct.pack` and `struct.unpack` functions.

Comment: _"392399" should be able to fit into 4 bytes._ - why would it?  "392399" consists pf six characters, one character requires _at least_ one byte.

Comment: OH wait, if I send it as an integer will that work? how do I do that if encode requires a string?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `str(SIZE_OF_FILE)` typesets the number using decimal notation - that is, you get the string `"392399"`, which is 6 characters (and 6 bytes in UTF-8). If you send only the first 4, you are sending `"3923"`.

What you probably want to do is use something like [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) to create a bytestring containing the binary representation of the number.

```
s.send(struct.pack(format_string, SIZE_OF_FILE))
```

Comment: And as a side node for the receiving side: recv(4) won't necessarily return 4 bytes. Always read from sockets in a loop.

Comment: @David Z what is format_string it says it is not defined.

Comment: @user5428151 Indeed, I haven't defined it. You should be able to determine what `format_string` should be by reading the documentation. (I was hoping that would be clear from context.)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the size as a string (`"392399"`), which is 6 ASCII characters and therefore 6 bytes. You want to send it as a raw integer; use [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to do that:

```
s.send(struct.pack(">i", SIZE_OF_FILE))
```

To recieve:

```
fileSize = struct.unpack(">i", conn.recv(4))[0]
```

The `>` makes it big-endian. To make it little-endian, use `<` instead. `i` is the type; in this case, a 4-byte integer. The linked documentation has a list of types, in case you want to use another one.